# Prevent page reload when form has been submitted

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I would like to prevent a page from reloading when submitting a form. The button has the following code:

```
<input type="IMAGE" border="0" src="/addToCartIcon.jpg">
```

This button is inside a form:

```
<form method="POST" name="myform" onsubmit="return BuyProduct(this,'1','0','False');" action="/shop/basket.asp">
```

So far, i've already tried using "event.preventDefault()" but this does not seem to work. Is there any other way that i can prevent the page from reloading when a user submits the form?

Comment: Use Ajax for form submission.

Answer (score 0):

In the `BuyProduct` function return `false` just before the function exits:

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) function to prevent the form submit.

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Using this form submit will not happen. if you want to do something without page load use jquery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for that

Comment: So it is not possible to have the form submitted AND preventing the page from reloading, at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Better use Ajax to submit the form. This will prevent the page from reloading.

Use the below syntax:

```
$("#FormID").submit(function(e) { //On submit

    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submission

    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //serialize form data
    var form_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action


    $.ajax({
        url: form_url, 
        type: GET/POST,      
        data: form_data,     
        success: function(returnhtml){                          
            $("#result").html(returnhtml); //display result in tag with ID "result"

        }           
    });    

});
```

Comment: I tried using this. But i get the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: GET is not defined
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:11:15)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (webshop.all.min.js?v=8.4.9.1400:5)
    at HTMLFormElement.h (webshop.all.min.js?v=8.4.9.1400:5)

Do you know how to fix this?